# Why does the ISR for a timer interrupt (LAPIC) takes 100us?

Tags: timer, linux-kernel, scheduler

I'm experimenting with the timer interrupt on x86 using Linux. In the experiment, I print the current time (TSC) and the next deadline set in `lapic_next_deadline()` function.

First, I see that the next time I reach this function (i.e., `lapic_next_deadline()`) is much later (i.e., ~100us later) than the deadline that was set in the previous invocation of this function.

Then I started printing the time (tsc) in `smp_apic_timer_interrupt()` function and compared it to the deadline that was set in the previous invocation of `lapic_next_deadline()`. I was still surprised to see the time to be much higher than what was set earlier.

After that, I used `trace-cmd`'s function graph to see how much time was being spent on each function. And I found out that the kernel remained inside `smp_apic_timer_interrupt()` for a little over 100us.

I am confused if this is how the `lapic_next_deadline()` supposed to work? I thought that `smp_apic_timer_interrupt()` should be called as soon as the time set in the previous invocation of  `lapic_next_deadline()` was reached. Am I missing something here?

For these experiments, I have made the kernel "ticked" by setting the following options in the config file before compiling the kernel:

```ini
CONFIG_TICK_ONESHOT=y
CONFIG_HZ_PERIODIC=y
CONFIG_NO_HZ=y
CONFIG_HIGH_RES_TIMERS=y
CONFIG_HZ_250=y
CONFIG_HZ=250
```

Please let me know if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: "*Please let me know if I am doing something wrong*" -- Well, using the system itself to "*print the current time*" (negatively) affects the system that you're also trying to measure. Have you even tried to estimate what that impact might be? Do you also understand the difference between *accuracy* versus *precision*? Apparently the use of the TSC has its pitfalls; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter  Study https://elinux.org/High_Resolution_Timers#How_to_detect_if_your_timer_system_supports_high_resolution Bottom line: is "*~100us*" an accurate measurement?

Comment: **smp_apic_timer_interrupt()** is not in the Linux kernel since version 5.8.

Comment: To overcome the negative impact of prints, I measure the tsc and store it to an array and then print the array after X invocations of lapic_next_deadline(). Across different values of X, the 100us latency does not change.

Comment: And yes, for these experiments, I am using Linux 5.2-rc7 and I cannot change it.

Comment: Like I said earlier, to understand why there was a discrepancy (of ~100us), I used trace-cmd and that showed me that kernel was spending a little over 100us inside smp_apic_timer_interrupt().